# php mail() from email not the same as what I sent through header

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send an email using the mail function, while the email goes through on my local, it is not on hosted server. The one thing that is very out of place on both servers is the "from" email address I am trying to pass through the header using mail().

Both servers are getting the same "from" email address to send in my code. But my email results are very different. There the "From" email address in the emails that are in my inbox have 
"myname@my-name.local" for my local server
"www-data" for my hosted server

What I have it set as in my email "from" header is: noreply@domain.com

```
$to = "my.name@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
$from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$date = date("F j, Y, g:i a");

$title = checkValue('title', $_POST['title']);
$first_name = checkValue('first name', $_POST['first-name']);
$last_name = checkValue('last name', $_POST['last-name']);
$email = checkValue('email address', $_POST['email']);
$state = checkValue('state', $_POST['state-province']);
$zip = checkValue('zip', $_POST['zip']);
$city = checkValue('city', $_POST['city']);
$country = checkValue('country', $_POST['country']);
$addressOne = checkValue('address 1', $_POST['address-1']);
$addressTwo = checkValue('address 2', $_POST['address-2']);

// get phone and format
$phoneArr = checkArrayValues($_POST['phone']);
$phone = '['.$phoneArr['0'].'] ['.$phoneArr['1'].'] ['.$phoneArr['2'].']';

// get fax and format
$faxArr = checkArrayValues($_POST['fax']);
$fax = '['.$faxArr['0'].'] ['.$faxArr['1'].'] ['.$faxArr['2'].']';

$message = checkValue('message', $_POST['message']);
$topic = checkValue('topic', $_POST['subject']);

$emailBody =  '
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HELLO</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <label>##Referrer##www.zout.com/contact-us##</label><br />
            <label>##Date## '.$date.'##</label><br />
            <label>##Topic## '.$topic.'##</label><br />
            <label>##First Name## ['.$first_name.']##</label><br />
            <label>##Last Name## ['.$last_name.']##</label><br />
            <label>##Street## ['.$addressOne.'], ['.$addressTwo.']##</label><br />
            <label>##Postal Code## ['.$zip.']##</label><br />
            <label>##City## ['.$city.']##</label><br />
            <label>##State## ['.$state.']##</label><br />
            <label>##Country of residence## ['.$country.']##</label><br />
            <label>##Phone## ['.$phone.']##</label><br />
            <label>##Fax## ['.$fax.']##</label><br />
            <label>##Email## ['.$email.']##</label><br />
            <label>##Message## ['.$message.']##</label><br />
        </body>
    </html>'; 
    $headers = -"From: noreply@domain.com" . "\r\n";
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    mail($to,$topic,$emailBody,$headers);
```

What is the cause for this and how can I fix it?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Please add your PHP-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set the "Reply-to" header as well. If the "from" doen't match the sender most email clients will ignore it.

Or you could use any number of pre-written libraries. [Here's](http://geneticcoder.blogspot.com/2014/08/wrapper-for-phps-mail-function.html) mine, for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer. I was able to fix it. Noticed a syntax error in my $header construction in the process.